# How can i do filtration search of channel files extension with low search?

Tags: search, low-search, filter, channel-files

Can i do filtration of channel files extension with low search ?

I want to search filtration of document types with channel files such as: pdf, doc. ppt, jpeg, etc using low search.

Please let me know, if you have solution.

FYI:

EE: 2.7.2

Low Search: 2.4.2

Channel Files: 5.2.8

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Low Search doesn't have *specific* support for Channel Files (CF), so whether the two play nicely together depends on how CF stores its (searchable) data. **If** CF stores its data in the native channel_data table, then you can use the [Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search) to search for substrings like `.pdf` etc. If it does not, then a custom filter/extension would be needed to add support for it.